# Return values in case of wrong inputs

Tags: java

This might sound very stupid. But Every time I start creating a new api, I find myself stuck on this question.

Lets say, I am writing a writer which takes in the input, writes it to a database or file and returns a boolean variable true/false.

If the writer returned true, that means the write was successful.
If the writer returned false, that means the write was unsuccessful.

Now lets say the input was null or empty string, in that case should writer return false or should it return True?

One obvious solution would be to throw some exception (may be illegalargument). But what if I don't want to throw the exception? Lets assume, I am just parsing some log entries and trying to write it in a file. Every time I an writing data, I am expecting true/false.

Comment: you can consider it as "false", as it is equivalent to writing nothing.

Comment: Depends on you, and the definition of a false return but if those are invalid inputs, you can (and should) throw an exception.

Comment: Returning `false` instead of proper info about problem is one of reasons why old File API was considered bad. More info at: http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks.

Comment: you asks here how your api should work..

Comment: Indeed @thomas my bad, it is painful to read my own comment !! (Edited ;) )

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. There may be duplicates for this, but on its own it's a valid question that's been properly asked. @quento He's not asking how his API should work, just a specific aspect of API design.

Comment: @G_H well here this is more than a simple design. A return value will depends on what you write. Yes there is some standardization about those but this will mostly depends on the methods. At least on the name of it. Here, we only have a specific input without know if this can or should be inserted in the DB

Comment: To make it short: don't use a boolean for such thing. The only valid return value would be `true`, because every `false` should be an exception with a proper information ___why___ it was unsuccessful (i.e. just `false` is very ambiguous). As @Pshemo commented, that design decision is why `File` is often useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you want to be done with the return value, and if the inputs can be sensibly handled.

If null or an empty String is not a valid input, usually some exception would be thrown because the user of your API did not respect its contract. But for some things such as logging, where success may not be critical, you may just wish to overlook it, write nothing and return the boolean.

It then depends on what the boolean should communicate to the user. If it must state that something was written away, only valid inputs successfully written should return true, a failure or incorrect input false. If you want to state that handling the input was successful, regardless of whether it was valid, you return true if something was written or a case like null/empty handled properly, false only on actual failures to handle sensible inputs. A user of your API may wish to retry the operation on a return value of false, but it would keep failing if the issue is due to the input itself, not some transient failure like a connection being dropped.

Maybe the real problem is that a boolean can have two values, while we have more than two scenarios. Returning some value to indicate success, failure or wrong input would be better. In lots of older APIs you'll often find integer return values to indicate the outcome (such as in many command line programs). In Java it would make sense to use an Enum. Values could be `SUCCESS`, `FAILURE` and `INVALID_INPUT`. The user of the API can then determine how to handle each case. What's more, it can be extended to cover other cases, such as different failure modes.

But keep in mind that at some point, this simply starts resembling a replacement for checked exceptions. In the end, the right answer depends on the API and how it should be used, and the discussion would probably be not just a technical one, but also a matter of style and preference.